# Save files and Applications to a Live Ubuntu disk

Tags: usb, unetbootin

I was wondering is itpossible and how could one save a document or/and application onto a  Live Ubuntu USB? I am on MacBook Air running OS X 10.8.5 I installed Ubuntu onto my USB using unetbootin.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is a persistent USB. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) page will walk you through the steps to set it up correctly.

**EDIT**
 Boot into your Mac, plug your USB drive in, open the drive and open the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

You should see an entry such as

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
```

a little further down you should see something like:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
```

if you add the word `"persisitent"` after `"casper"` and before `"quiet"` you should be able to boot and have persistence!

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent quiet splash --
```

Comment: Thanks man! The page didn't help me much but if I do some reserch I'll find something that does.

Comment: @Vombocorn check my edit above